# Twitter api with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, twitter, twitter-oauth

Can someone please help me and tell me that what is wrong in my code, that I am not able to make successful calls to the api. Everytime when I run the code on my localhost, it goes into the error block.

```
(function(){
angular.module('app')
    .controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController($resource, $http){
    var vm = this;


    //serviceModule.factory('twitter', function ($resource, $http) {
        var consumerKey = encodeURIComponent('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        var consumerSecret = encodeURIComponent('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

        var credentials = btoa(consumerKey + ':' + consumerSecret);
        console.log(credentials);
        // Twitters OAuth service endpoint
        var twitterOauthEndpoint = $http.post(
            'https://api.twitter.com/1.1'
            , "grant_type=client_credentials"
            , {headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credentials,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
                        }}
        );
        twitterOauthEndpoint.success(function (response) {
            // a successful response will return
            // the "bearer" token which is registered
            // to the $httpProvider
            //serviceModule.$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + response.access_token
            console.log("response");
        }).error(function (response) {
              // error handling to some meaningful extent
              console.log("error " + response);
            })
            }

}());
```

Comment: *"when I run the code on my localhost, it goes into the error block."*. It also explains what's wrong in network tab.

Comment: @dfsq I even tried on http server, but still the same problem.